# Access axios in webworker error ReferenceError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is not defined

Tags: reactjs, axios, web-worker

i create react app using create-react-app i want to use web worker in app 
for file upload using axios but axios or any library i import in worker file  this error raise ""ReferenceError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default is not defined""

```
import axios from "axios";

export default function AppWorker(){

self.addEventListener("message", e => {

// eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals

    if (!e) return;

    console.log(e.data.data)

    axios.get("www.example.com).then((e)=>{

      console.log(e)
    })

}

)}

// worker file




///////////////////////////////////
export default class WebWorker {

    constructor(worker) {

        const code = worker.toString();

        const blob = new Blob(['('+code+')()']);

        return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
    }
}
// worker setup file


///////////////////////////////////////

    import React, { Component } from "react";

    import worker from './worker.js';

import WebWorker from './workerSetup';

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

    this.worker = new WebWorker(worker);

  };

  addFile = e => {};

  handleChange = e => {

    console.log(e.target.files[0]);

    const fileObj = e.target.files[0];

    this.worker.postMessage("Hello World");

}

render() {

    return (

      <div>

        <input

          onChange={this.handleChange}

          placeholder="filer Uploader"

          type="file"

        />)
}

}
//home component
```

Comment: I know this might seem obvious, but did you install axios via npm or yarn first? `npm install axis --save`

Comment: Check your `node_modules` directory to see if the axios folder is in there. If its not then you know thats your problem.

Comment: i install it with npm and it is in node_modules but same error